# Why isn't std::optional<boost::variant<A, bool>> successfully constructed from `std::optional<A>`?

Tags: c++, c++17

`std::optional` has copy conversion and move conversion templated constructors that make it possible to construct an instance of `std::optional<B>` with an instance of `std::optional<A>` when `B` is constructible from `A`.

Unfortunately, it seems that those constructors do not work with a `boost::variant` that has `bool` within the allowable types. Why is that the case?

You can see that the limitation applies to `std::optional` but does not apply to `boost::optional` in the following godbolt. Code is also reproduced below.

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/PKTEET

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <optional>

struct A
{};

struct B
{
    B(A) {}
};

void f() {
    boost::optional<A> boptA;
    boost::optional<B> boptB{boptA};
    std::optional<A> soptA;
    std::optional<B> soptB{soptA};

    {
        boost::optional<boost::variant<B>> vB;
        vB = boptA; // 1. success
    }

    {
        boost::optional<boost::variant<B, bool>> vB;
        vB = boptA; // 2. success
    }

    {
        std::optional<boost::variant<B>> vB;
        vB = soptA; // 3. success that compares with #1
    }

    {
        std::optional<boost::variant<B, bool>> vB;
        vB = soptA; // 4. compilation error that should have compared with #2
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `std::variant`?

Comment: I plan to, but I'm currently in the process of migrating `optional` first and I thought this was an interesting problem.

Comment: It certainly is. I would underline that the problem is truly only for `bool` (actually I see it fails also for `std::optional<bool>`!), because `int` doesn't seem to be a problem, for instance.

Comment: What is the actual compiler error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`boost::variant<B, bool>` claims to be constructible from `std::optional<A>`, because `bool` is constructible from `std::optional<A>` (due to the [explicit conversion operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator_bool)).

Because of that, `std::optional<boost::variant<B, bool>>` will try to construct the contained object directly from `std::optional<A>` without unwrapping.

But `boost::variant`'s implementation uses an implicit conversion internally, and you can't implicitly convert an `optional` to `bool`, hence the error.

Comment: I am confused by your answer. You say that the error is caused by `boost::variant`'s implementation, yet `boost::optional` compiles as expected whereas `std::optional` doesn't. Here's a new godbolt that shows that case #2 does construct the variant with an instance of `B` rather than a `bool`. Unless I have misinterpreted your answer, I would have expected line 29 to have printed `1` rather than `0`. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3bdsqa

Comment: `boost::optional` and `std::optional` have different rules for when they unwrap.